# Unexpected module object on Runtime Execution

Tags: python

I have two modules mod1.py and mod2.py. In the first one i have the following code:

```
# mod1.py
# -------
import inspect

def get_module_object():
    curr_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    return inspect.getmodule(curr_frame)

# =======================================

# mod2.py
# -------

from mod1 import get_module_object

print(get_module_object()) # RETURNS : <module 'mod1' from '...\mod1.py'> 
                           # Expected: <module 'mod2' from '...\mod2.py'>
```

I could fix this if I set a paramter in the function signature which accepts a current_frame = inspect.currentframe() (**def func (curr_frame**): ...), but this implies that I import everytime the *inspect* or *sys* (sys._geframe(...)) to be able to obtain the current frame, which will be tedious, error prone and will violate the DRY - principle.

P.S.

I had similar problem with the ****file****, which will be set on import time and will produce again some unexpected (for me) results. As analogy to the above example will return the full file path of mod1.py and not mod2.py.

The main point should be to encapsulate as much as possible from the logic in mod1 and to use it in the rest of the modules mod2 ... mod_n.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Try to replace `inspect.currentframe()` by `inspect.currentframe().f_back` to use the second-to-last frame instead.

Comment: Hi Michael Butscher and thank you, it seems to work, i will try to scale it to my project ! :)